# Is there any way to apply Media Queries on Frameset elements to make website mobile responsive?

Tags: html, responsive-design, media-queries

Actually I am trying to make my desktop web page mobile responsive.

```
  <frameset rows="80,*" frameborder="no" border="0" framespacing="0">
    <frame src="/showTopFrame.do" name="topFrame" scrolling="no" noresize="">
    <frameset cols="20%,80%*" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" border="0">
    <frame src="/showLeftNav.do" name="menu" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" noresize="true" scrolling="auto" framespacing="0" border="0" frameborder="0">
    <frame src="/blank.html" name="information" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto" framespacing="0" border="0" frameborder="0">
    </frameset>
    </frameset>
```

[image]

Please help me if I can achieve this with media Query or any other simple way.

Comment: Why Frameset ??? why not iframes ???

Comment: I can't help it, because in existing application they have used frameset everywhere. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using media queries in your css.

like this:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {


}
```

You can find more information about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: Right, and in this {} I can place my css code. But my question is how can I apply CSS on frameset or frame tag. 

I don't think if media query can answer my question.

Comment: @AmitKansal You can put a class on your frameset using class="classname" and moodify this class in your media query. .classname { css }

Comment: Thanks Smits, it would be very helpful if you can explain it with an example. i.e As you said I can place classname on frameset and can modify it with media query. But I am still struggling how can I change my ROWS and COLS defined in FrameSet. 



Once again thanks for your helping hand.

Answer (score 0):

you need frameset id.

```
var width_size = '';

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    width_size = window.innerWidth;
    frameResize();
}, true);

function frameResize(){

    if (width_size > 1080) {
        document.getElementById('mainFrameset').rows='80,*';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('mainFrameset').rows='40,*';
    }
}
```